# Access Tasks in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

The lines with `// TODO` are available in `Task` Section in Eciplse IDE. How can we access the *List of Items* in `Tasks` Section.

Presently we can add `tags` using **IMarker** library.  But to access them from Task Section is not available.

Screenshot of Eclipse IDE
[image]

Comment: This is very unclear. Are you saying you are creating TODO items in your plugin and they are not showing up in the TODO view? If so show us your code.

Comment: `TODO` tags are visible in the Task Section, but I want to access the list of `TODO` items in the task section using any method. i.e I have 3 TODOs in task section, Now I want to print the location(Line no.) of the TODO task. Hope it's clear.

Comment: No it isn't clear. Acess where? In a view? In code in a plugin?

Comment: Access in a code in a plugin

Answer (score 0):

You use the `IResource` `findMarkers` method to get any marker.

```java
IResource resource = .... any file, folder, workspace root ...

IMarker[] markers = resource.findMarkers(IMarker.TASK, true, IResource.DEPTH_ZERO);
```

`IMarker.TASK` gives you the tasks list. `IResource.DEPTH_ZERO` searches child resources as well.

You get the line number from a marker with:

```java
int lineNumber = marker.getAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, -1);
```